# How to create a telnet server locally?

Tags: windows, telnet

I'm running windows XP on my dev machine. I need to create a telnet server to test an application locally. Is there any program or application that I could use to do that? The only thing I need is for my program to be able to connect on port 23 to my dev machine, send some data, and for the receive data to be printed/echoed out/logged somehow by the receiving program.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you may really need is something that emulates the echo daemon in Unix.  Not sure if Cygwin has something like that, but I'd look there first.

If it's really a telnet server that you need, you can use PC Telnetd (http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/telnetd/) or you can set up telnetd using Cygwin.  There are surely other options as well.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you can use [netcat](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/nc/) (as far as I remember, there are several different versions of netcat. The link is the one that is used for Fedora). There might be a cygwin version available readily, that would have been my first choice if working on windows.